# Pourquoi mon bot ne veut il pas effacer les messages

Tags: python, discord.py

I wanted to make my bot respond to a command by deleting messages but an error appears:

```
 File "C:\Users\Mathis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Mathis\Desktop\dev-prog\infinity\lize\boot lize.py", line 41, in on_message
    number = int(message.content.split()[1])
IndexError: list index out of range←[0m
```

and here is my code :

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("!del"):
        number = int(message.content.split()[1])
        messages = await message.channel.history(limit=number + 1).flatten()
        for each_message in messages:
            await each_message.delete()


bot.run('TOKEN')
```

PS: can we do all the script on a .py file?

Comment: Please use *only* English on SO. Note also that we expect questions to only contain relevant, technical information, and no thanks or anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that `message.content` contains at least 2 words before trying to use `[1]`.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("!del"):
        words = message.content.split()
        if len(words) > 1:
            number = int(words[1])
            messages = await message.channel.history(limit=number + 1).flatten()
            for each_message in messages:
                await each_message.delete()
        else:
            print("Need number of messages to delete")
```